# Query a nested table in SQL3

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't figure out how to select info based on the values inside a nested table.

This is my nested table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE results_type AS OBJECT
(
    class_name       VARCHAR(10),
    grade            NUMBER(2)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE results_tab_type AS TABLE OF results_type
/
```

And here is my main table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE student_type UNDER person_type
(
    date_birth      DATE            ,
    weight          NUMBER          ,
    year            NUMBER          ,
    adress          adress_type     ,
    results         results_tab_type
)
/
```

How can i select all the students that have `grade > 10` and `class_name = 'Calculus'`

Comment: Tag the correct database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Just query the table as normal and use a correlated table collection expression to check that the required values exist in the nested table:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   students s
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   TABLE( s.results )
         WHERE  class_name = 'Calculus'
       )
AND    EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   TABLE( s.results )
         WHERE  grade > 10
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TYPE person_type AS OBJECT(
    id NUMBER
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE student_type UNDER person_type
(
    date_birth      DATE            ,
    weight          NUMBER          ,
    year            NUMBER          ,
    -- adress          adress_type     ,
    results         results_tab_type
)
/

CREATE TABLE students OF student_type (
  id PRIMARY KEY
) NESTED TABLE results STORE AS students__results;

INSERT INTO students ( id, results )
SELECT 1, results_tab_type( results_type( 'French', 12 ), results_type( 'Calculus', 8 ) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, results_tab_type( results_type( 'French', 7 ), results_type( 'Calculus', 9 ) ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ededb2a8ee67c963823004d92665036d)*